# Excel exported data

Tags: microsoft-excel, export

I have a spreadsheet that is exported data from a program.
Is there a way to find out which program it was exported from? (Any embedded information when exported?).
TIA
G Cap

Comment: Share the data and maybe someone can search it for you to confirm otherwise... for an Excel Spreadsheet some sort of data (meaning content within) or perhaps metadata identifying something about the application it was generated from??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is dependent on the program that exported the data, if it includes author infomation, or a read-me page in the spreadsheet.  A program may or may not include any infomation in the export, it depends on the developer.  Depending on the computer you use, you may use the Preferences window on Windows computer, or Get Info on a Mac to view metadata that may indicate where the data came from.